# Change button's title on selecting table view cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I have some buttons stating: "Tap to fill in..". When tapping on them a table view pops up with options. How do I link these options to the button so the "Tap to fill in.." gets replaced with the data/row the user has selected? I have no clue where to start, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (void)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
     NSString *newText = [youArray objectAtIndex:row]; //yourArray contains your datas (of type NSString in this example)

     //consider your button btn is an inst var
     [btn setTitle:newText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I did what you suggested but my button doesnt seem to be updating the field.. Could you be a little more specific please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: My array:  NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                      @"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",nil];
 self.tableViewArray = array;

Comment: The tableview code: - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
 return [tableViewArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SimpleTableIdentifier"];
 if (cell == nil) {
  cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"SimpleTableIdentifier"];
 }
 
 cell.textLabel.text = [tableViewArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 
 return cell;
}

Comment: In my code, change youArray by tableViewArray, and btn by the name of the ivar corresponding to the button to update.

Comment: [_industry setTitle: @"myTitle" forState: UIControlStateNormal]; Changes the title of the button to myTitle. But when I try to use your code to dynamically change the title by selecting a row in the tableview it just wont update..

Comment: I think the problem might be that im using 2 different viewcontrollers? 1 Viewcontroller has the button in it, and the other viewcontroller has the tableview in it.

Answer (score 0):

// create following Property in viewcontroller .h file which pops up on button click

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton  *button;
```

// call popup view on button click as follows

```
YourTableViewController *tables = [UITableviewController alloc] init];
tables.button = buttonObjectWhoesTextYouWantToChange;
UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:tables];
popover.delegate = self;
popover.popoverContentSize=CGSizeMake(280.0, 327.0);
```

// Now add this single line in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method of tableviewcontroller

```
self.button.text = cell.textLabel.text;
```